# GitHub how to give a user admin access based on repo's tags

Tags: github

Is it possible to give a specific user admin access to certain repositories in your organisation based on their tags?

I'm trying to give a member admin access specifically to several repositories (10+) related to a group of projects, but not all repositories. I can manually do that but I wonder if there's a more efficient way.

I haven't been able to find the answer anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unaware of a way to grant permissions by repository tags, but a [GitHub Team](https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-organizations-and-teams/about-teams) would be a good option for this.

Create a new GitHub Team, [give it appropriate access](https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-organizations-and-teams/managing-team-access-to-an-organization-repository) to the 10+ repositories, and then assign the member admin to that team. They should then be able to administrate only the added repositories.

Comment: Thank you @Adil, I guess that's the only option for now. I'll look around more and if I can't find anything else, I'll mark your answer as correct.